# How can I automatically delete dates and times in rows with EmEditor?

Tags: date, emeditor

I have a text file.
There are hundreds of different filenames in the text file.
However, it says different date and time at the end of each file.
Sample: `life-in-cosmos-2021-11-11-12-45-46` or `life-in-cosmos-2021-11-11-12-45`.

In order to change the names of the files in bulk, I first need to delete the dates in this text file.
So I want to automatically delete the dates and times in each row.
However, I don't know anything about this.
And I don't know how to use macros.
Therefore, if there is a solution for this, can you provide an answer with a picture or video?

In order to explain my request more clearly, I present 2 examples.

Example:

Original Text: `cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC-2020-09-11`

The result I want to do: `cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC`

Example 2:

Original Text: `cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC-2021-04-02-12-37-49-utc`

The result I want to do: `cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC`

Comment: Can you please write a sample file exactly (but simplified way)?
Is your file content like this: ? 
`life-in-cosmos-2021-11-11-12-45-46 (NEWLINE) life-in-cosmos-2021-11-11-12-45`  What is your exptected result? Is your expected result like this? `life-in-cosmos- (NEWLINE) life-in-cosmos-`

Comment: Thanks for updates. You have only one file to edit? Is a date always at the end of each line? No characters exist after each date (except `-utc`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a date is always at end of each line, you can replace a regular expression with an empty string. To do this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the `Replace` dialog box, and set following options:

**Find**: `-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[0-9\-]*?(\-utc){0,1}$`

**Replace with**:  (blank)

Set the `Regular Expressions` option

2. First, click the `Find Next` button to highlight matches to make sure they are correct. If the matches are incorrect, you will need to adjust the regular expression.
3. Finally, click the `Replace All` button to remove all matched strings.

**Before replace**

```
cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC-2020-09-11
cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC-2021-04-02-12-37-49-utc
```

**After replace**

```
cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC
cosmos-lights-colors-T5DAPC
```

[image: EmEditor - Replace]

Comment: It worked, thank you. Now I'll have to do some research before I can bulk change the file names with this data.